# Is it safe to uninstall VS Express after installing VS Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, uninstallation, visual-studio-express

A couple of days ago, I installed Visual Studio Express for C#; yesterday I installed Visual Studio Ultimate. Since I will no longer use the former, is it safe to uninstall it?

Comment: As far as I understand the Express edition is isolated from the Ultimate one so it should be safe to remove Express edition. However there can be some caveats...

Comment: Yeah, the caveats is what I'm worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web right after having installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and it still works perfectly. Also tried after a reboot, just to be sure.