# Uninstalling VS 2013 Express after installing VS 2013 Community and CUDA

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I am learning about GPU Programming using CUDA and I just realized that VS Express does not support plugins. I have installed VS 2013 Community and I was wondering if it is safe to uninstall VS 2013 Express after I have installed community and CUDA. Will doing such a thing 'break' anything ? I am only decent with programming so I have no idea about paths and environment variables and what not. Will my old projects still work if I launch them with VS community ?

I am aware of this thread [Is it safe to uninstall VS Express after installing VS Ultimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140278/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-vs-express-after-installing-vs-ultimate) but was wondering if uninstalling will affect any paths or so.

Comment: Best bet is to repair the Community Edition after uninstalling Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases it's safest to repair the edition you want to keep after a deinstallation. While the Visual Studio installation itself will probably survive, other components, such as Windows SDKs and Targeting packs may get damaged.

First uninstall the Express edition(s) and then go to Programs and Features to repair the Community Edition.